# Как сделать чтобы не все элементы адаптивного меню скрывались на малых разрешениях в Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap, media-queries

Всем привет. В общем ситуация такая, нужно чтобы на разрешении меньше 992px меню скрывалось за гамбургер, но не все меню, телефон должен остаться до разрешения 768px, меньше 768px, телефон должен скрыться за гамбургером. Как это реализовать в бутстрапе?
Для понимания прикладываю скриншоты из макета.
Так должно быть от 768px до 992px:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так должно быть от 0 до 768px:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
              <div class="logo">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                  <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Логотип">
                </a>
              </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item main_menu_list_item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Главная</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item main_menu_list_item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">О компании</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item main_menu_list_item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Недвижимость и переезд</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item main_menu_list_item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="navbar-text d-flex">
            <div class="icon">
              <img class="modal1" src="img/phone.png" alt="icon">
            </div>
            <div class="phone">
              +7 (495) 12-321-345<br>
              +7 (495) 12-321-345
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Вынесите телефона из блока div collapse

Comment: Но а как мне его потом занести обратно? Потом он должен будет скрыться на разрешении меньше 768px. А показываться по нажатию на гамбургер вместе с остальным меню..

Comment: Как вариант оставить и там и там, просто использовать в media display:none когда необходимо.
Либо можно заморочиться с JS, но обойтись css будет проще я думаю